# Who is the Tooth Fairy really in Terry Pratchett's Hogfather?

Tags: movie, terry-pratchett, discworld

In [*Terry Pratchett's Hogfather*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terry_Pratchett%27s_Hogfather) (television adaptation) Susan finds

> the "Toothfairy" lying in bed

towards the end of the Hogfather story, who is this?

How is this the

> "Original Bogeyman?"

In what sense? Is this any relation to the monster scaring the two children at the begining, the one who briefly talked to Susan and saw her brief eye sparkle hinting of her special nature?

Please bear in mind I have not read any of the *Discworld* books, I've only seen a few of the films.

Comment: I've edited this question to fit the spoilers into the text better. If you don't like this feel free to roll back.

Comment: @Pureferret That's fine,thanks

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In the Discworld universe, bogeymen are anthropomorphic personifications of childhood fears. I.E they pop out of thin air if enough people believe in them. Other anthropomorphic personifications include the gods and DEATH. The Tooth Fairy was the very first bogeyman to appear. After many many years of interracting with children, he became fond of them and decided to protect them from possible manipulation through their discarded teeth. So he set up the Toothfairy franchise to collect them and keep them away from the wrong hands.

Comment: In hindsight it made sense; several of these new personifications spawned into existence before I got what was going on. Somehow I thought that (in the film) the tooth bogeyman appeared similar to the same moaning monster that visited the two children and got politely outed by Susan towards the beginning, so I wondered if there was a deeper connection.

Comment: I don't think boogiemen in Discworld are anthropomorphic personifications so much as some sort of psychic vampire that feeds off of fear. Boogiemen seem to be more like a kind of animal (e.g, I think they can breed, since there was an "original") than a belief-based anthropomorphization, but I don't think the texts are explicit either way.

Comment: @Tacroy - This article in L-Space http://wiki.lspace.org/wiki/Bogeymen claims that the first bogeyman (at least) was an anthropomorphic personification. The rest may indeed be biological descendants, though its not clear in the article.

Comment: @SystemDown It's not clear in the books either :) I just got the impression from the boogie's story that it had a biological origin that was enhanced by belief, but it's been a while since I read the book.

Comment: @Tacroy: both of these are true.  Bogeyman exist and breed because many people believe that they do so.  It's like when enough people believe in a god that has created Discworld, then he will have created it.

Comment: In the interests of fairness, as well as close acquaintance, I believe in Bilious, the Oh God of Hangovers.